# I bus, You bus, They bus, REBUS

Tags: wordplay, rebus

These may be too easy...

1 :    [image: image1]

2 :    [image: image2]

3 :    [image: image3]

4 :    [image: image4]

5 :    [image: image5]

6 :    [image]

Well, here are my intended answers, anyways.
*SPOILERS ! ! ! ! ! !  *

> 1. Face palm (－‸ლ)
>  2. Beetle Juice
>  3. Dog Tired
>  4. Serial Comma
>  5. Stargaze
>  6. ButtonHooking

Comment: thanks fro the answers, perhaps `,,,,,,` would have been a better clue for #4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Partial and dubious answer**

I don't really believe half of these -- the only one I'm really sure of is #3 -- but:

> 1. face + palm -> FACEPALM.
>  2. (VW) Beetle + (kinda) juice -> BEETLEJUICE (movie title, presumably deliberate corruption of "Betelgeuse").
>  3. DOG TIRED (though this one doesn't work in the UK where we have tyres rather than tires).
>  4. (Don't have a good answer for this yet.)
>  5. star, gays in -> STARGAZING??
>  6. (Don't have a good answer for this yet.)

Comment: for three it may have something to do with the fact that there's heads, not corpses, and maybe a slash? another punctuation mark?

Comment: Could do. I also wonder about "serial comma" (which is a thing but doesn't really come near enough "serial killer" to work for me) or "comma slice" (there is a grammatical solecism sometimes called a "comma splice") which also doesn't seem like it quite works.

Comment: I also keep thinking of run on sentence for some reason. Like the comma is on the loose or on the run, but I don't think that fits either.

Answer (score 5):

I think

4:

> "Comma, kill"   "Comical"

which is wrong

days later I come up with a better answer

> "Prime suspect" 
>  In mathematics the apostrophe is called "prime", the severed heads and evil grin clearly make it a suspect.

Comment: Funny, but not my intended answer. +1 for ingenuity; I love seeing the different interpretations.

Answer (score 4):

My answers:

1.

> Facepalm?

2.

> Betelgeuse

3.

> Dog tired

4.

> Serial comma killer?

5.
Don't know yet. @Gareth's answer is better than anything I've come up with.

6.

> Button hooks?

Comment: I want #6 to involve buttons too, but can't make visual sense of if second and third frames if her head is really meant to be a button. And unfortunately "buttonhooker" doesn't seem to be a word even though there are such things as button-hooks.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I changed #6 to properly show perspective on the second, third *and* fourth frames. That should button things up nicely...

Comment: That certainly seems to confirm that it's a button! I looked through all the "button X" / "button-X" words in the OED and didn't find anything that seemed to fit, though. (Again, there are button-hooks but apparently not button-hookers. Maybe we're aiming for "buttonhole" with some horrible ho/hole pun going on??)

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure,

2:

> Carpool

and #3 maybe:

> Dog track

Answer (score 2):

I like Gareth's answers, here are my attempts for the rest

4:

> Death sentence (with the comma separating the death clauses)

6:

> Busting buttons (idiom for "very proud")

Answer (score 2):

6.

> Ball Buster -- They look like Dragon Balls, and the cop is busting her for prostitution.

Answer (score 2):

4. I am fairly certain is:

> Killer Quote

Answer (score 1):

on top of Gareth's answers, maybe:
4.

> killer coma

6.

> bitch button (https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bitch%20button)

Comment: But she's a ho, not a bitch.